# PHP accelerator installed but symfony 3 not recognized it

Tags: php, symfony, apcu

When i install symfony, it recommeneded me:
*Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).*

I installed apcu according to http://www.ivangabriele.com/php-how-to-install-php-accelerator-in-xampp/

**APCu** installed successfully and phpinfo() show it enabled but symfony still get me this message:
*Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).*

Comment: APCu is not an accelerator. It is a caching system.

Comment: apcu is apc for php 7.0 ?!  php 7.0 hasn't apc extenstion

Comment: APCu is the user caching functions from APC only. APC's old opcode caching functionality (which was accurately deemed an accelerator) is now in core. http://news.php.net/php.internals/66531

Comment: More evidence: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apcu.php "APCu is APC **stripped of opcode caching**."

Comment: but i can't install apc for php 7.0.

Comment: Correct, you can't, because its functionality is already in PHP7 itself. An accelerator is likely unnecessary in PHP 7.

Comment: but symfony not recognized it.

Comment: Take that up with Symfony. Symfony 3 came out in November 2015. PHP7 came out in December 2015. Chances are it's just an outdated recommendation and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that info @ceejayoz. I wonder if you have a link that describes why an accelerator in PHP 7.0 is unnecessary, I would appreciate that.

Otherwise Jinx, you can try php70u-opcache. That's what I used:

```
yum install php70u-opcache
```

This is on CentOS, you may have a different Linux distro, so the commands may be different. Also it may not be 'php70u'. But when you run `php bin/symfony_requirements`, you won't get the message about the accelerator.

Comment: I linked it in the comments. http://news.php.net/php.internals/66531 links to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/optimizerplus which was a vote to integrate the Zend Optimizer+ accelerator into PHP 5.5. It is noted as implemented successfully in that version.